Are module finite algebras over complete local Noetherian rings semiperfect?
Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a commutative Noetherian local ring, which is complete by the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic filtration. Let $A$ be a (not necessarily commutative) module finite $R$-algebra. Then, is $A$ a semiperfect ring? I came up with this question after seeing Are module finite algebras over semiperfect rings again semiperfect?.

If your "module finite" means that A is a finitely generated R-module, then it's Example 23.3 from the 'First courses in noncommutative rings' by Lam.

@Denis T Thanks a lot!
